# How to split a polyline into straight segments in python?

Tags: python, split, line

I have a GeoDataFrame containing informations about roads in Poland. The data comes from OSM. Most of larger or/and curvy roads are already divided into smaller, straight sections, yet some of them are still curvy/crooked.

I need at least 10 reputation to post images and this is a new account, so I posted it on imgur and here is a link to an example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdVvw.png

My question is: is it possible to split a polyline into as many straight segments this polyline contains using python? And if the answer is yes, then how to do it?
Closest problem I have found is this one: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/226056/postgis-how-to-split-a-polyline-into-straight-segments yet it applies to PostGIS.